# Is the IP address a valid NuGet address? 93.184.215.200

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I work for JobCorp a government agency. Our firewall policies are constantly being updated and recently DHS flagged what I believe is a NuGet IP address.  Below is my network admin's response when I asked him to figure out why NuGet is not working...

## Is the IP address a valid NuGet address?  93.184.215.200

The IP 93.184.215.200 was flagged by DHS as having involved in election security compromises so it is being blocked. I will do more digging here. 
If you have any contacts at nuget.org, try to confirm whether it is the correct IP for api.nuget.org.  I don’t want to have a compromised DNS send us to a malicious IP.

Comment: Belongs on [sf]

Comment: @JimGarrison I doubt this would be on-topic for Server Fault either.

Comment: I confirmed it was blacklisted and nuget is aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a NuGet IP. I believe it is part of their CDN for downloading NuGet packages.

```
C:\>nslookup api.nuget.org
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    cs10.wpc.v0cdn.net
Addresses:  2606:2800:11f:7de:d31:7db:168f:1225
          93.184.215.200
Aliases:  api.nuget.org
          db16.wpc.azureedge.net
```

Answer (score 1):

api.nuget.org is based on Azure CDN, which is in turn based on Verizon Digital Media CDN, you can check from here: http://www.whatsmycdn.com/?uri=api.nuget.org.

In other words, 93.184.215.200 is IP address from EdgeCast, check here: http://www.whatsmycdn.com/isEdgeCastIP?ip=93.184.215.200